# Invalid Signature when Submitting Mac App

Tags: app-store-connect, code-signing, mac-app-store, appstore-sandbox

I have an app on the Mac App Store which is at version 1.0.

Later, I upgraded to the Mountain Lion GM and the Xcode 4.4 GM.

I've added features to the app and I'm trying to submit it as version 1.2.

It passes validation and gets successfully submitted, but I keep getting "Invalid Binary" and "Invalid Signature" errors.

When I try

```
 codesign -dvvv myapp.app
```

It successfully prints out the identifier, authorities, etc.

I'm completely lost because nothing has changed except for the code and the inclusion of sandboxing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up deleting all my profiles and certificates and re-downloading them.